# Data Structure and Algorithm (Graph related)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

You are given a set of N sticks, which are lying on top of each other in some configuration. Each stick is specified by its two endpoints; each endpoint is an ordered triple giving its x, y, and z coordinates; no stick is vertical. A stick may be picked up only if there is no stick on top of it.

a. Explain how to write a routine that takes two sticks a and b and reports whether a is above, below, or unrelated to b. (This has nothing to do with graph theory.)

- Compute ranges of the two sticks on x and y axes.
- If the intersection of x ranges of a and b or the intersection of y ranges of a and b are zero, two sticks are not in the same place.
- If both are not zero, then calculate the point at which two sticks cross(intersection of the two lines in the x-y planes) and the stick with the higher z-value at that point is on top.

b. Give an algorithm that determines whether it is possible to pick up all the sticks, and if so, provides a sequence of stick pickups that accomplishes this.

I do not know what algorithm I should utilize.

- for question A, Please let me know if it is not correct or if it is vauge.
- for question B, please let me know which algorithm could be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say it's possible to pick up all the sticks.

If you know if a stick is above another stick (as you described, by comparing x-y and then z), then you have a comparison method to compare sticks between them and you can **sort** them. Once they're sorted, you start with the one on top and remove it, then take the next and remove it...

The issue here is we don't know if the above is possible. Knowing the above algorithm gives you a hint: we can't remove all the sticks when we can't sort all the sticks, i.e. if we **don't** have loops such as a < b < c < a.

So you need to find out of your ordering method is **transitive**. Being transitive means that if a < b and b < c then a < c, for all of your sticks.

If your ordering method is transitive, then you can remove all the sticks. If it's not, then you can't remove all the sticks.

To do this, you can manually sort your sticks using a **bubble-sort-like algorithm**:

For each stick:

- Go linearly through the ordered sticks array until you find a stick that's superior.
- Remember the index, but still go through the rest of the array to check that all following sticks are inferior
- If they're not, stop because your order is not transitive.

This has O(n^2) complexity. I don't know if you can do better.